# Pre-calculate a JSX variable before re-rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, render, state, jsx

Is it possible with react to prepare a variable to be displayed in the JSX, before the re-render() function is called?

Ex:

```
count_function() {
    e.g.
    return number_of_children_having_state_#
}


a_prerender_function() {  // Which one componentWillUpdate ?? But in that case, how to pass it to the render function
   // const count = this.count_function()   // This can't be put in state, otherwise 'infinite-loop'
}


render () {

    // const count = this.count_function()   // This is only called at the first render! But not on next re-render

    return (
        <div>
           {count}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I can't update this variable in the render() function because I need to refresh it at each re-render, and the render function is only called once.
I can't use a state variable for that otherwise I get an infinite loop of re-rendering.

Comment: Wrong, render function is called everytime the component need to rerender. Read through react docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Can you post a more complete version of your code? Since render should be called each time it renders, if it appears that render isn't being called each time then maybe something else is the matter, for example, with your count_function.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve. But you do need to understand the lifecycle of the react component (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html). If you want to set the component state based on the count_function() result, then you need to be careful in your choice of place to do this. Never set state in render() or componentWillUpdate() or functions called from these. If you need to set an initial state for the component before it mounts (renders for the first time), do this in the constructor() of your component.

Comment: What is your count variable counting?

Comment: It is counting the number of nested children that have two specific states variables set to e.g. 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript

```js
interface Props<T> {
  value: T;
  render: (value: T) => JSX.Element;
}

type IVariable = <T>(props: Props<T>) => JSX.Element;

const Variable: IVariable = props => props.render(props.value);
```

```js
<Variable value={price * quantity} render={amount =>
  <p>
    Amount: {amount} {plural('coin', amount)}
  </p>
} />
```

Javascript

```js
const props => props.render(props.value);
```

```js
<Variable value={price * quantity} render={amount =>
  <p>
    Amount: {amount} {plural('coin', amount)}
  </p>
} />
```